# Rails: simple 'Setting' model with key, value attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m new to rails and I’ve a pretty simple situation to solve but I cannot figure out how to proceed with it.

I want to create a simple ‘Setting’ model with `key, value` attributes. ‘SettingsController’ may contain 2 public methods only `index` and `update`. Only `index` action will have a view file with a form whose fields will represent each record of the ‘Settings’ table.

I want to be able to define some permitted keys (may be using some private method) and I want the form to create or update the record of relevant fields on submitting the form to `update` action.

Now,  I don’t know exactly what code should I use in controller for `index` and `update` actions and in the index view file for the form which can create/update multiple records at the same time and can show updated values all the time. How do I proceed with it?

**Update # 1:**

I've managed to write some controller actions as below (based on some tutorial):

```
class Admin::SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
  end

  def update
    setting_params.each do |key, value|
        Setting.where(key: key).first.update_attribute :value, value
    end

    redirect_to admin_settings_path, notice: "Settings saved."
  end

  private

  def setting_params
    params.require(:settings).permit(:site_title, :site_desc)
  end

end
```

The form code in index view template is given below:

```
<h1>Settings</h1>

<%= form_tag admin_settings_path, method: "put" do %>

    <p>
        <label>Site Title:</label>
        <%= text_field_tag "settings[site_title]" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Site Description:</label>
        <%= text_field_tag "settings[site_desc]" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= submit_tag "Save settings" %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

This forms saves the values correctly in the database but the saved values doesn't persist in form fields.

Comment: Why don't you include whatever code you already wrote so we can see how you're thinking about your problem.

Comment: I've managed to write some code based on tutorials (post updated above), but as my requirements are slightly different from the tutorial I'm facing issue to persist saved values in form fields.

Comment: Are you open to using a gem to get what you want, or are you determined to create your own mechanism from scratch?

Comment: Apparently it seems to have a simple problem, I'm not sure why it would need a separate gem. So, if solution is infact simple I would prefer a custom code approach otherwise a gem will do fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the `index` action. `Setting.all` returns an array of `Setting` record, not a hash like { key1: value, key2: value } which I think you are trying to achieve. The form, therefore, displays data improperly. You can try this:

```
def index
  @setting = {}
  pairs = Setting.pluck(:key, :value)
  pairs.each { |key, value| @setting[key] = value }
  @setting
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I assume I'll also need to modify the form code in index view file, how should I modify it?

Comment: Well, I was able to persist the saved value in the field by using a second parameter based on `@setting` variable like this `<%= text_field_tag "settings[site_title]", @setting["site_title"] %>`, so the issue is now solved, thanks again.